# How to properly write many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've reviewed how the join table between `Book` and `User` was written to ensure correct FK's were used. What I'm confused about is why the Book class seems to raise the error `InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'mapped class Book->book' has no property 'user'` when it wasn't mentioned that any relationship field should be included on it. I tried including one but it still threw a similar message.

I'm expecting to be able to create a several new instances of User and be able to add at least 2 favorite books to each.

```
class Book(db.Model):
    """Book model."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    publish_date = db.Column(db.Date)

    # The author - Who wrote it?
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'author.id'), nullable=False)
    author = db.relationship('Author', back_populates='books')

    # The audience - Who is this book written for?
    audience = db.Column(db.Enum(Audience), default=Audience.ALL)

    # The genres, e.g. fiction, sci-fi, fantasy
    genres = db.relationship(
        'Genre', secondary='book_genre', back_populates='books')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Book: {self.title}>'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Book: {self.title} {self.author}>'


class User(db.Model):
    """User model."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    favorite_books = db.relationship(
        'Book', secondary='favorite_book', back_populates='user')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<User: {self.username}>'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User: {self.username}>'


favorite_book_table = db.Table('favorite_book',
                               db.Column('user_id', db.Integer,
                                         db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                               db.Column('book_id', db.Integer,
                                         db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
                               )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `User` model, you declare a `favorite_books` relationship with the `Book` model.

```py
favorite_books = db.relationship(
        'Book', secondary='favorite_book', back_populates='user'
)
```

In the relationship, `back_populates='user'` is telling SQLAlchemy that the user can be accessed from a `Book` through the book's `user` attribute, but no user attribute has been defined on the `Book` model.  You need to add a relationship on `Book` that points to `User.favorite_books`, like this:

```py
user = db.relationship(
    'User', secondary='favorite_book', back_populates='favorite_books'
)
```

It is possible to declare both side of the relationship solely on `User` by using [backref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/backref.html#using-the-legacy-backref-relationship-parameter) instead of `back_populates`:

```py
favorite_books = db.relationship(
    'Book', secondary='favorite_book', backref='user'
)
```

However `backref` is considered to be a legacy construct in SQLAlchemy 2.0, so it shouldn't be used in new code.